# Why augmented assignment for the sets behave differently?

Tags: python

I am using a normal union over the sets in two ways i.e. `x|=set([4,5,6])` and `x=x|set([4,5,6])`, why do they behave differently?

For simple integer variable its working same i.e. whether i am using `x=x+1` or `x+=1` the result is the same.

```
x=set([1,2,3])
y=x
x|=set([4,5,6])
x
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
y
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])



x=set([1,2,3])
y=x
x=x|set([4,5,6])
x
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
y
set([1, 2, 3])  # why does the value of y remain unchanged.
```

Comment: Because `x|=set([4,5,6])` is inplace and `x=x|set([4,5,6])` is an assignment that creates a new object

Comment: @roganjosh Do you know a reason making it in-place? That is the confusing part, I would way. When encountering that expression, I would assume a new set being created, as my mental model is that `v (op)= x` is just short-hand for `v = v (op) x`. It seems unpythonic, or I might not be Dutch enough.

Comment: @Johan there's nothing unpythonic about it IMO. If I didn't care about `y` going forwards then I really wouldn't care that the name is bound to an object that was mutated. `y = x` is the most unpythonic here because it's a pointless name in this context. For things like numpy where speed is important, in-place operations like this make a lot of sense

Answer (score 4):

you are creating a new `set` and assign it to `x` here

```
x = x | set([4, 5, 6])
```

from here on `y` is independent of `x` (they are the names of different `set`s).

on the other hand in-place assignment in your first example does not create a new set; it just modifies the current instance in

```
x |= set([4, 5, 6])
```

now `y` still refers to the same `set` as `x`. you can see the difference by printing

```
 print(id(x))
 print(id(y))
```

before and after the assignments.

it may be instructive to visualize the difference on [pythontutor.com](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit).

---

everything i said above is valid for *mutable* objects (e.g. `set`s). for *immutable* objects the in-place assignments behave just like the 'normal' assignments; i.e. for `x` an `int`: `x += 1` is the same as `x = x + 1`.

Comment: Why it's not happen in the case of variable:
>>> x=2
>>> y=x
>>> x+=1
>>> x
3
>>> y
2

Comment: as i said: `int`s are immutable. `x+=1` has no other meaning than `x = x+1`; both return a new instance.